# JBoss AS7: How to read datasource pool statistics with JMX

Tags: jboss, statistics

In JBossAS4, the MBean jboss.jca.ManagedConnectionPool allows to access, e.g., the number of used and the number of available connections of a data source. This MBean is no longer available in JBossAS7.

How can these values be accessed in JBossAS7?  There seems to be a way: the JBoss Adminstration Console offers the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK on windows or Linux  you can can use Jboss cli (client interface).
This is on JBOSS AS 7.1.3

On my windows box this is what I did (My jboss home is C:\jboss-eap-6.0)

Execute the following batch file

```
C:\jboss-eap-6.0\bin\jboss-cli.bat
```

It will take you to a prompt

```
[disconnected /]
```

You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands
.
Now type connect. for all other command try help. This will allow you to browse the JMX tree (May be my terminology may be wrong).

```
[disconnected /]connect

[standalone@rama-local:9999]
```

Lets say my data  pool name is "OracleSampleDS"
Then you can query the stats by using below command

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=OracleSampleDS/statistics=pool:read-resource(include-runtime=true)
```

Here is the output I got

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "ActiveCount" => "0",
        "AvailableCount" => "20",
        "AverageBlockingTime" => "0",
        "AverageCreationTime" => "0",
        "CreatedCount" => "0",
        "DestroyedCount" => "0",
        "MaxCreationTime" => "0",
        "MaxUsedCount" => "0",
        "MaxWaitTime" => "0",
        "TimedOut" => "0",
        "TotalBlockingTime" => "0",
        "TotalCreationTime" => "0"
    }
}
```

In case you changed the hostname during jboss installation to anything other than localhost you can edit jboss-cli.xml

I tried the same command on linux by using **jboss-cl.sh**

In case you have separate profile (mostly if you use domain mode) then specify the profile name as below.

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/data-source=OracleSampleDS/statistics=jdbc:read-resource(include-runtime=true)
```

Here the profile I was using in domain mode was **"full-ha"**

Once you are connected to the Jboss command line tool you can use few commands like

- ls
- pwn
- connect
- quit

(Try it out)

Also there is

```
http://loclahost:9990/management/subsystem/datasources/data-source/OracleSampleDS/statistics/pool?include-runtime=true
```

The ports my differ please see your hosts.xml (in  case you are using domain mode) 
or standalone.xml to see which management ports you have exposed by checking 
Look at the section that says **http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm"**

Answer (score 1):

There is a MBean `jboss.as:subsystem=datasources,xa-data-source=DATASOURCENAME_Pool` which has all of the configuration attributes, but it does not feature statistics. According to this [thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/195949), the statistics are only exposed to the management API (http access with JSON export).